# How to clear value of particular textbox from all text boxes on C#.Net button click..?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have kept 10 Text box in a form to enter the value to my Sql database. And After a Entry i don't want to clear all my text box in a button click event, I need to clear only 4 text box to be cleared on a Button click event to make an another Entry. So please someone help me to clear this..

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly assign empty string to Text property of those four textboxes on button click. Something like.

```
textBox1.Text = "";
textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

`textBox1.Clear();` 
Is all you need to use for the selected boxes.

Answer (score 0):

on button click

```
TextBox1.Text="";
TextBox2.Text="";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use the List and Lambda Expression For this:

```
List<TextBox> tb=new List<TextBox>() {textbox1,textbox2,textbox3,textbox4};
tb.Foreach(u=>u.Text="");
```